# Backtesting in pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, back-testing

I am trying to create a simple backtesting code in Tradingview. The idea is to buy once price breaks above 40 weekly moving average and sell when price closes below 40 weekly MA, with a stoploss og 5%. I have gotten  the crossover strategy to work, I think but it seems that my returns, depend entirely on how many contracts I trade. I just want to see the plain and simple return of the strategy, regardless of contract size. Also I am struggling to implement the stop loss into my code. This is my code so far.

```
//@version=4
strategy(" SMA cross")

sma40 = sma(close,40)

long = close > sma200
sell = close < sma200

start= timestamp(1995,6,1,0,0)
end= timestamp(2020,6,1,0,0)

if time>= start and time <=end
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,1000, when= long)

strategy.close("Long", when = sell)
```

The part where is says 1000 has significant change on my return. I just want to see the neutral return form this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

long = close > sma200
sell = close < sma200

long = close > sma(close,200)
sell = close < sma(close,200)

long = crossover(close,sma(close,200))
sell = crossunder(close,sma(close,200))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).